# ssh tunneling for sftp in MobaXterm in Windows system

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, tunnel, mobaxterm

How to set ssh tunneling for sftp in MobaXterm?

I know PuTTY can set ssh tunneling for sftp when there is a gateway between your local computer and the remote server.

But I can not find the same function in MobaXterm.

In MobaXterm, there is only proxy (Socks4 and 5) or Web proxy instead of ssh tunneling.